# confusion in the output of cellfun function

Tags: matlab

I want to find out the elapsed time, in the function file I wrote this piece of code;

```
function elapsed = elapsedTime(d1,d2)
%Input d1 = '2010/12/04 12:00:00'
%Input d2 = '2010/12/14 13:06:36'
d1r = regexp(d1,'((/|:)?|[ ])?','split');
d2r = regexp(d2,'((/|:)?|[ ])?','split');
elapsed = cellfun(@minus,d1r,d2r,'UniformOutput',false);
end
```

the output is the following:

```
ans = 
    [1x4 double]    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]
```

This output format is no good as I cannot use it to find the elapsed time!

How can I use it to map it to the actual output, should it not give an cell array like the following:

```
ans = '0000' '00' '00' '01' '06' '36'
```

is there any way to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

You are subtracting strings, and expecting that numbers will result (in the form of strings).

What do you expect to happen if you'd do:

```
>> '3' - '10'
```

? If you say the answer should be `'-7'`, then how about

```
>> 'a' - 'B'
```

?

The most comprehensible solution is to convert the strings to numbers, carry out the subtraction, and convert back to string:

```
elapsed = cellfun(@(x,y) ...
    num2str(str2double(y)-str2double(x)), ...
    d1r, d2r, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with dates / timestamps you should probalby consider using `datenum` and `datestr` instead of re-inventing the date-parsing wheel:

```
function elapsed = elapsedTime(d1,d2)
%Input d1 = '2010/12/04 12:00:00'
%Input d2 = '2010/12/14 13:06:36'
fmt = 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS';

elapsed = diff(datevec( [d1;d2], fmt ),1,1)
end
```

This would return:

```
elapsed =

     0     0    10     1     6    36
```

Another bonus here is, that you can very easily adapt to changes in the date-format. You might also want to look at the `etime` and `datevec` function.